# How to determine number of touches that are scrolling UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I am trying to determine number of finger touches on UITableView when `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` is called & perform some task accordingly.

Two approaches that I have tried so far are:

1. Subclassing UITableView to override `touchesBegan:withEvent:` -
   The problem with this approach is that this method is only fired when there is 'some' tap on the screen, not when the user just quickly scrolls without resting the finger.
2. Using `uipangesturerecognizer` to detect number of touches. - 
   I am using it in the following way:

---

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *taps = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
taps.maximumNumberOfTouches=4;
taps.minimumNumberOfTouches=1;
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:taps];
```

And then

```
-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"BEGAN - %d",sender.numberOfTouches);
    }
}
```

Although I am able to get the number of touches with this approach, but the problem is that it is overriding actual scrolling (normal scrolling is not happening).

Please suggest where I am wrong or what else shall be done.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method -(NSUInteger)numberOfTouches of UIGestureRecognizer could tell you how many touches on it.

Comment: Yea.. thx for such a simple workaround.. it works & I can use it... but through this I am only able to count touches on `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`. It resets to zero on `viewDidScroll`. It would be perfect if it is possible to specifically count touches when fingers lifted!

Comment: Have the same problem. Im trying to determine number of touches in - (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch method. It always return 0 here :(