# UIGestureRecognizer overriding "long presses" in UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I am using `-(NSUInteger)numberOfTouches` method of `UIGestureRecognizer` class to count number of touches in a `UITableViewController`. ([my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500549/how-to-determine-number-of-touches-that-are-scrolling-uitableview))

Although I am able to count them correctly, but it is overriding touch events in such a way that tableView's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is only called on a very short tap.
On long press, the cell does gets highlighted, but `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not fired.

Please guide what shall be done.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things to try.  First of all, your immediate problem is that the gesture recognizer is probably waiting to see if you're going to add taps/touches to satisfy it's requirements for firing.  You could also add a long touch recognizer that calls your didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but I would first watch the very good WWDC session on gesture recognizers from 2010 first, given you're a paid developer, and that would give you a good idea of how to correctly implement multiple gesture recognizers so that they fire when you want them.

Answer (score 0):

call it from viewDidLoad() also I implement this code for monotouch it give an idea about longPressGestureRecognizer.

```
void AddGestureRecognizersToImage (UIImageView imgView)

 {

 var longPressGesture = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer (this, new Selector

 ("ShowResetMenu"));

  imgView.AddGestureRecognizer (longPressGesture);

 }

 [Export("ShowResetMenu")]

void ShowResetMenu (UILongPressGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer)

{

 if (gestureRecognizer.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began)

{

 var menuController = UIMenuController.SharedMenuController;

     var resetMenuItem = new UIMenuItem ("Reset", new Selector ("ResetImage"));

 var location = gestureRecognizer.LocationInView (gestureRecognizer.View);

 BecomeFirstResponder ();

 menuController.MenuItems = new [] { resetMenuItem };

 menuController.SetTargetRect (new RectangleF (location.X, location.Y, 2, 2),  gestureRecognizer.View);

            menuController.MenuVisible = true;

            imageForReset = gestureRecognizer.View;

        }

    }
```